# Сериализация в С++

Tags: c++, json, xml, ооп, serializable

Прошу дать ссылки, или, если есть желание, рассказать вкратце о красивом, удобном способе сериализации полей класса в *C++*. Приведу пример (не уверен, что так можно, но хотелось бы) - использовать ***свойства***, аналогичные свойствам в *C#*, перед полями, которые будут учавствовать в сериализации (но: *рефлексия* ?), все автоматически упаковывается в *JSON/XML* (если это важно, то *JSON* меня интересует в большей степени), аналогично читается из *JSON/XML* и инициализирует соостветствующие поля объекта.

Comment: @Abyx, 21 века? :)

Comment: Жаль, что не увидел ранее. Это, возможно, поможет (если вдруг еще кому интересно): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11031062/c-preprocessor-avoid-code-repetition-of-member-variable-list/11744832#11744832

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Универсального решения нет - и быть не может без рефлексии - которая будет - возможно - только в следующих версиях плюсов - да и с ней - если будут накладные расходы - универсального решения не будет. Вы можете выбирать из [библиотек](https://github.com/search?l=C%2B%2B&o=desc&q=serialization&s=stars&type=Repositories&utf8=%E2%9C%93). По скорости или удобству использования.

"свойства, аналогичные свойствам в C#, перед полями" реализуются всеми этими либами через макросы (слегка приврал), многое из того, что раньше можно было достичь только макросами сейчас можно достижимо средствами шаблонов C++, но:

- вот [пример](https://meetingcpp.com/index.php/br/items/a-third-way-to-use-boost-serialization.html) использования boost::serialization c макросами.
- [Пример](http://cecilsunkure.blogspot.ru/2012/10/c-reflection-type-metadata-part-2-type.html) добавления рефлексии с шаблонами и макросами.
- [RTTI](http://www.garret.ru/cppreflection/docs/reflect.html) с макросами

Сами по себе макросы - зло, но бывают и необходимым злом.

я для себя взял rapidjson (пушо очень быстрая) и сделал вокруг нее пару обвязок типа stringValue / intValue. В принципе, достаточно удобно пока.

По поводу бустов: попользуйтесь, наверняка будет полезно. Выпиливать куски не надо, на рантайм это не повлияет, может быть только на время компиляции. Если подойдет другая либа для json/xml ([POCO](http://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.XML.html)) например, берите ту, что вам удобнее в использовании. Вам главное инкапсулировать как можно больше, чтобы вы могли сменить потом либу, а не ловить ее вызовы по всему коду

Comment: Не могли бы Вы привести пример использования макросов в таком контексте ? Вообще всегда думал, что макросы в C++ - зло )

Comment: Как на счет Boost'а ? Вы никогда не имплементировали ту его часть, что работает с метаданными ? Можно было бы использовать его, но слишком уж награможденно. Попробую что-то выпилить, но боюсь, не хватит знаний в данное время для такой работы )

Comment: @isnullxbh обновил ответ, не тратьте время на выпиливание, можете во внутренности посмотреть, для самообразования )

Comment: Спасибо Вам ! Годный ответ )