# Как сохранять данные в файле txt C++

Tags: c++

Дело в том что, мне нужно сохранить данные в файле, таким образом, чтобы оно не перезаписывалось опять, а прибавлялось к имеющему переменному опять.
Например:
Программа имеет условие, где нужно посчитать очки игроков, и уже к имеещему добавить еще.

Comment: Считываете имеющиеся данные, обновляете, перезаписываете файл заново (или используете бинарный и записываете на старое место).

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Сериализация в С++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/555710/%d0%a1%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d0%a1)

Comment: @VTT не дубликат. Тут вопрос про простую дозапись, без сериализации

Answer (score 1):

Можно открыть файл [с помощью fstream](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/openmode) c флагом `std::ios_base::app`

Примитивный пример - сколько раз запустил, столько строчек в файле.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::fstream testfile("e:\\test.txt", std::ios_base::app);
    testfile << "test" << std::endl;
}
```