# Как создать признаки Хаара для распознавания лиц?

Tags: c++, машинное-обучение, распознавание-образов

Я пытаюсь понять как создать самостоятельно признаки такие как эти: [image: Пример каскадов из оригинальной статьи:], самое неприятное, что в статье никаких объяснений нет

И я даже нашёл код: но, я абсолютно не понимаю как оно будет выглядеть в итоге.
Код из вопрос про количество признаков:

```
const int frameSize = 24;
const int features = 5;
// All five feature types:
const int feature[features][2] = {{2,1}, {1,2}, {3,1}, {1,3}, {2,2}};

int count = 0;
// Each feature:
for (int i = 0; i < features; i++) {
    int sizeX = feature[i][0];
    int sizeY = feature[i][1];
    // Each position:
    for (int x = 0; x <= frameSize-sizeX; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y <= frameSize-sizeY; y++) {
            // Each size fitting within the frameSize:
            for (int width = sizeX; width <= frameSize-x; width+=sizeX) {
                for (int height = sizeY; height <= frameSize-y; height+=sizeY) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Ссылка на оригинальную статью: http://lear.inrialpes.fr/people/triggs/student/vj/viola-ijcv04.pdf

Ссылка на вопрос из которого взял код для вопроса: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707620/viola-jones-face-detection-claims-180k-features

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться как сгенерировать все признаки и как их хранить.
Спасибо за любую помощь :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Что тут происходит: Для получения значения признака вычисляется разность между суммированной интенсивностью пикселей темных и светлых областей.
- Что это даёт: Если значение признака ближе к 0, то значит пиксели в областях имеют сходную интенсивность. Если оно дальше от 0, то значит между областями имеется контраст. Таким образом, большие значения признака для блоков вида A и B говорят о наличии в блоке границы темных и светлых областей, а для блоков вида C и D - о наличии в блоке линии.
- Почему блоки протяженные: Во-первых, вычисление суммарной интенсивности - это быстрая операция. Во-вторых, увеличение размера блока позволяет обрабатывать большие области не требуя четкого соответствия обнаруживаемых особенностей изображения расположению блока, т.е. например обнаруживаемая граница темных и светлых областей может быть не строго вертикальная или горизонтальная, или может иметь дефекты.
- Откуда берутся конкретные размеры и расположение этих блоков: В простейшем случае они расставляются вручную, подгоняясь под особенности целевого (участка) изображения, чтобы накрывать области, в которых ожидаются границы областей или линии.
  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А можете подсказать как их хранить в файле например, учитывая код написанный в вопросе (он как раз и создаёт все эти признаки)?
Это нужно сделать, т.к для создания каскадов их надо выбирать, т.е их нужно сделать много и где-то хранить.

Comment: Сериализуйте их в JSON например.

Comment: А как? 
Я просто не представляю как это выглядеть должно
На данный момент у меня уже есть обученный классификатор (он глупый из-за неправильных признаков), а в нём признаки только размера как изображение 32 * 32 в моём случае, в который хранится так:
координаты левого верхнего и правого нижнего угла черной области.
Как мне хранить признаки используя координаты, или это невозможно?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/555710/%d0%a1%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d0%a1

Comment: Понял, спасибо.
А если нетрудно можете дать пример как будет выглядеть любой признак (ну и его картинка) в json виде?

Comment: Как координаты и размеры прямоугольника.

Comment: На первой итерации кода как будет этот признак при параметрах:
sizex=2, sizey = 1, x = 0, y = 0, width = 2, height =1
Ну где будет в нём расположена черная область, а где белая, даже если просто в координатах?

Comment: Храните сначала перечень блоков типа A (т.е. вертикальная граница), потом типа B и т.д. Прямоугольник делится на равные части.

Comment: А можно пример ну координат для блока типа А.
Ну т.е как его задать через параметры из кода?
Я только это не могу понять

Comment: Я уже сам вроде смог понять, огромное вам спасибо